# How do I modify this code so that it will print the pattern correctly?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(2):    
    for j in range(1,11):
        print(j," ",end="")
    print()
```

I need to print this pattern, but I can't figure how to get it to subtract 1 on the next line. Please help.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Do print (j-i, " ", end="")

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you meant?

```
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(1, 11):
        print(j - i, end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: @YolandaHui So `j - 1`, is this your code? Do you understand what it is doing?

Comment: how do you come up with j - i?

Comment: On the first run through the `i` for-loop, `i` is `0`, so `j - i` is always equal to `j`. On the second run through, `i` is `1`, so `j - i` is always equal to `j - 1`. This means that the first line will be the numbers 1 through 10, and the second line will be the numbers 0 through 9.

Answer (score 2):

Another way, just for fun :) would be limiting the range of `j` with current value of `i`:

```
>>> for i in range(1, -1, -1):
        for j in range(i, 10+i):
            print (j, end=" ")
        print()


1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

OR

```
>>> for i in range(2):
        for j in range(1-i, 11-i):
            print (j, end=" ")
        print()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension you can do like this also: This is different approach.

```
print ("\n".join([" ".join([str(j) for j in  range(1,11)])] + [" ".join([str(i-1) for i in range(1,11)])]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(2):    
    for j in range(1,11):
        print(j - i," ",end="")
```

if you want results in one line try this

Comment: how do you come up with j - i? I know how it works by thinking about the iterations. But I just can't think about coming up with it in the first place

Comment: this is a loop in side another loop..., when first loop increment to 0 (as you use range(2) it starts from 0) , then in second loop (inner loop) has to go from 1 till 10 as you use range (1,11) and in each increment it will print the value corresponding to "j" with space, then it will go back to main loop there the value change to i = 1, and again second loop executed...

Comment: In your case first loop you print number from 1 - 10 and next loop 0 - 9 continously we can find common nature from first set and second... accordingly we can get j - i will fine... as at first  i  = 0, j = 1 ... 10 and when i = 1, still j = 1... 10 to get values  0..9 we have to reduce value of i from it....

Comment: further, since it is small case we can find pattern simply to get better learning try some sites like projecteuler and hackerrank...